# Lxml parse DIV inside Tag from HTML

Tags: python, lxml, discord.py

I want to parse big HTML Text from a website.
So i Have parsed the Div and now I want the Content inside the Tag for example:

```
<div id="lala"><p>I WANT</p> <ul><li>THIS</li></ul>. <p>All of them</p></div>
```

This is my following code:

```
patchpage = requests.get(href)
        tree = html.fromstring(patchpage.content)
        patch_message = tree.xpath('//div[@class="messageText"]')
        for item in patch_message:
            await client.say(item.text.strip())  # This is bugging and give me error
        return await client.say(patch_message)
```

for now patch_message gives me:

```
[<Element div at 0x29c4be2fa98>]
```

Not really what I except :/ Can someone tell me how to parse the div content to python?

Comment: Have you tried BeautifulSoup ?

Comment: No, because all BeaufitulSoup Tutorials I found is with static html code. I get my HTML from a page which can change (i want to get the newest topic from a board and catch the text from this post) I have to put a URL into it:  for example: `newspage = requests.get('http://google.de')`

Comment: From this page, i get the full HTML code and then i search for divs I need etc. and Now i found the div but needs the content

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

You just need to exclude the None objects from being stripped.

```
for item in patch_message:
    if item.text:
        print item.text.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

> **text_content**():
>
> Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of its children, with no markup.

To extract all text content from every `div` tag in your `patch_message` list, simply use `item[0].text_content()` for every item.

`tree.xpath()` returns a list of found elements.

```
patch_message = tree.xpath('//div[@class="messageText"]')
        for item in patch_message:
            await client.say(item[0].text_content())
        return await client.say(patch_message)
```